# Image view to fill screenwidth on different devices

Tags: android, android-imageview

Im trying to make my app look good on different devices. I've tried it on a Galaxy S2, And a Google Nexus 7. My image covers the width on theS2, but not enterily on the Nexus. Why? What am i doing wrong here?

Here's code for my ImageView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/actionbar"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rect"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: would be helpful to see your entire layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this -->

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/rect"/>
```

Comment: Just notice that `fill_parent` is deprecated, you should use `match_parent` instead.

Comment: **yeah**, I know that, `fill_parent` is used if you want to develop your app for all new and old version Android.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the width & height of the `ImageView` to `fill_parent`

Comment: Yeah, but when I do that my Image View jumps down to the middle of the screen? It is placed into a relative layout.

Comment: Make sure the RelativeLayout is set to fill_parent too

Answer (score 0):

Set the scaletype attribute of imageview